# Manipulating Array Values

Tags: php

What would be the easiest way to take some $_POST textinput data that looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string() "The Black Keys - Gold On the Ceiling
    Angeline - Blackout
    Allele - Closure
    etc"
)
```

And turn it into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string() 'artist:"The Black Keys" track:"Gold On the Ceiling"'
    [1] => string() 'artist:"Angeline"  track"Blackout"'
    [2] => string() 'artist:"Allele"  track"Closure"'
    etc
)
```

Comment: What do *you* think is the easiest way? Where are you stuck at when trying to implement this easiest way?

Comment: Use `explode()`. Try it and post a new question if you can't get it working.

Comment: I've used explode and split the string based on \n so they're all separate array values, but I don't know how to manipulate the values to add the artist and track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Code in action: [eval.in](http://eval.in/31658)

```
$string = "The Black Keys - Gold On the Ceiling
    Angeline - Blackout
    Allele - Closure
    etc";
        print $string;

    $exploded_string = explode("\n",$string);

    foreach($exploded_string as $child_string){
    $array = explode(" - ",$child_string);
    $output[]= "artist:\"".trim($array[0])."\" track:\"".trim($array[1])."\"";
    }
        print_r($output);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I realize it was a really newbie question and I liked being able to look at what was happening with the prints. It works perfectly, and best of all, I understand it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `explode()`. You can then pass that into a `list()` if you want to. Something like this might work for you:

```
$lines = explode('\n', $_POST['textinput']);

for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    list($artist, $track) = explode(' - ', $lines[$i]);
    $processed_line = Array('artist' => $artist, 'track' => $track);
    $lines[$i] = $processed_line;
}

var_dump($lines); // Should output something like the example in your question
```

There's some excellent documentation on [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) and [`list()`](http://php.net/list) available on PHP.net.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both yours and Sumoanand's were very helpful! I chose the other as it was technically what I needed, but I learned from this as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump` might be what you are looking for. `explode` and `implode` are quite handy too